# MySql where clause does not reognize number

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

Could you please tell me what should I change to get the right results?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
where Genre = 'Comedy' and Revenue > 300000000
order by Release_Date desc
```

MySQL does not recognize 300000000. I want to retrieve rows where revenue is greater than 300mlns. Please, check my screenshots. I tried to change the datatype for Revenue column from text to double, decimal, and float but it did not work, an error occurred. Maybe because of text datatype it wont work?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sQZu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWLT8.png)

Comment: You need to use a number data type. What error are you getting when you change type from text?

Comment: You already asked a question about the right data type for this column: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099091/how-to-determine-the-right-datatype-for-columns Why did you chose text as its data type?

Comment: @forpas it is a different table. I haven’t put text into datatype, it was generated automatically. So as I understood, I have to create table datatypes manually every time because MySQL doesn’t recognize them properly

Comment: You could replace `Revenue` with `Revenue+0` which forces a datatype conversion, but that's ugly and inefficient

Comment: Store numbers as numbers, not as strings.

Comment: how are you creating tables, that they are ending up with the wrong data type?  maybe start with that

Answer (score 0):

The commas and dollar signs need to be removed.